# If element is X left then animate another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to anuimate an element on my site, but only when that element comes in to view.

To do this im checking to see when my wrapper div is X left, then fire the function. My only problem is nothing is happening, nor showing up on my console.

Ive tried adding an alert to my function to see if it fires only i dont see the alert. Can anybody see what im doing wrong?

```
var width = 200;

setInterval(function(){
    if ($('.wrapper').css('left')<width){
         $('.left-liftdoor').animate({
            left: -50
             }, 2000, function() {
         });
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem may be, that `$('.wrapper').css('left')` in your case returns string with unit (like '100px' or so) and your condition is not met. Parse the output of `.css('left')` or convert it to number using parseInt to properly check if value is less than given *width*.

Comment: Or, if possible, use offsetLeft.